# Migrating Silverlight application to HTML 5

Tags: html, silverlight, migration, dashboard

Currently we have application in Silverlight which contains a dashboard. The dashboard was developed in Silverlight.
Now we want to migrate the Silverlight dashboard app to HTML 5.0 so that the app can run on iPhone, iPad & android phones.

How we can migrate Silverlight application to HTML 5?
Also, do we need to use any third party custom control for dashboards in HTML 5.0?

Comment: They are two totally different technologies, with entirely different ways of doing things. There's no magic wand you can wave to convert the application.

Comment: @Polynomial Downvote a bit harsh. Still useful question

Comment: @polynomial OP is asking how to reimplement in HTML5. This is a common problem. Yes, Silverlight is different, but if his UI lends itself to a pure HTML5 implementation this is a good way to go (especially considering that MS has quietly killed Silverlight).

Comment: @DavidLively MS didn't say they were going to kill it, they just said they were going to leave it in the woods to fend for itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert you graphics from XAML to SVG. If you have the designs for this project, then you might want to take a look at [Adobe Illustrator CS5 HTML5 Pack](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/illustrator_html5/), which lets you "Save As SVG". You should keep everything vector based so it scales to iPhone, iPad and Android.

Then you need to transfer your UI behaviour to javascript. I suggest using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) by Steve Sanderson. I would combine this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for ease of use.

As @Polynomial mentioned in his comment, there is no "convert to HTML" package per se, but with a little know-how you will be able to migrate.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this project http://www.cshtml5.com/ . It might help in some simple cases.

Answer (score 2):

This may not solve your problems at this moment, but there is a project under development to rebuild Silverlight without using a plugin. The project has been under development for almost a year and the website just recently launched @ <s>http://fayde.wsick.com/.</s>
DISCLOSURE: I am affiliated with this project.